# How to redirect mobile users to mobile style and Back to the original style on PHP

Tags: php

i used this code on http://mobiledetect.net, to redirect users to mobile style

```
// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {

}

// Any tablet device.
if( $detect->isTablet() ){

}

// Exclude tablets.
if( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() ){

}

// Check for a specific platform with the help of the magic methods:
if( $detect->isiOS() ){

}

if( $detect->isAndroidOS() ){

}
```

But , i want to put a link or Button on `mobile style` to return users to the `original Style` , without turning them Automatically again to `Mobile Style` , how i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a variable from the link, like `?mob=false` and then check for it at the top while you're doing the mobile check.

```
$mob = true;
if(isset($_GET['mob'])){
    $mob = $_GET['mob'];
}
if ( $detect->isMobile() && mob !== false ) {
   //mobile stuff
}
```

Comment: Good trick but did not work,the link already have a variable `?styleid=5` and i used it on my code `if( $detect->isMobile() && $_GET['styleid'] !== 5)`

Comment: you can add multiple $_GET variables in the url with the `&` like `?var1=xyz&var2=foo&var3=bar`

Comment: thanx brother , it's working now , i used session `if( $detect->isMobile() and $vbulletin->session->vars['styleid'] !== 1)` , I have another question if you allowed to me , i want remove by Automatically `&styleid=x` or `?styleid=x`  from any and all links on Browser address i think i must use `header('')`